# Problems generating new Line using BufferedWriter in foreach loop

Tags: java, eclipse, io, bufferedwriter

If I have the following foreach loop that writes car properties to a text file:

```
for(Cars car: carList){

writer.writer(car.toString()); // toString is overwritten in Car class

}
```

this writes the data correctly only that all the data is on the same Line and not spaced. 
The writer object has its own newLine() method and BufferedWriter doesnt allow regular expressions. I need to assign each object of car written to a new line on the text file.

Comment: `writer.writer(car.toString() + "\n");` ?

Comment: this creates a newLine after the loop has complete

Comment: If that's the case, I'd be very much interested in the implementation details of your `writer`, because it isn't BufferedWriter. Actually, it already can't be because that has no `writer`-method expecting a String. What *are* you using exactly? You tag with and mention BufferedWriter, but use neither that or the java.io.Writer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this:

```
writer.newLine();
```